# Javascript prototype shared variable

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any way that a variable inside a prototype structure can have the same value across all instances? In my case I need to load the Google API, but I want to make sure that the script is only loaded once.

```
SharedVariable.prototype.createCache = function ( key, requestFunction, callback ) {

    // <-- this.cache should be a variable shared across all instances

    if ( !this.cache[ key ] ) {
        this.cache[ key ] = $.Deferred( function( defer ) {
            requestFunction( defer );
        }).promise();
    }
    return this.cache[ key ].done( callback );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrQkP/

`createCache` has three parameters:

1. `key` is basically the src of the script
2. `requestFunction` is a function that is only called once per `key`.
3. `callback` is a function that is called multiple times

This function only works if `this.cache` is a "global" variable, which should have the same values in all instances. Currently it has a different value for each instance, that's why the code is not working properly. Is something like that possible with prototype?

Comment: Are you creating "instances" of "SharedVariables"? Or do you want all "SharedVariables" to "share a property"? Please make the class name unambiguous.

Comment: @Bergi In my fiddle I'm creating two instances (`new SharedVariables`). Each instance has a variable called "cache". I want "cache" to have the same value across all instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `cache` property part of the prototype:

```
SharedVariable.prototype.cache = {};
```

Now all instances of `SharedVariable` reference the same cache object.

**Edit based on your JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/BrQkP/1/

You create the `cache` as an Array in JavaScript, yet you seem to be setting string key values. You are abusing Arrays in JavaScript, as they are supposed to be integer indexed keys starting at zero. Instead, create an empty object using curly braces as I mentioned above.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BrQkP/2/